# Windows | Defining a Keyboard Shortcut to Open Applications with Start Key

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts

Is it possible to define in Windows 19 a keyboard shortcut to open (execute) an executable/shortcut using the Start (Windows) key? For example, to have a shortcut `Start + T` to open a terminal application (similarly to Linux)?

Also, suggestions shortcut managers suggestions for Windows would also be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use a third-party product such as
[AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/).

You would use a AutoHotkey script such as:

```
#n::Run Notepad
#w::Run Wordpad
```

to run Notepad on <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> and Wordpad on
<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>.

After installing AutoHotKey, put the script in a `.ahk` file and double-click
it to test. You may stop the script by right-click on the green H icon in the
traybar and choosing Exit.
To have it run on login, place it in the Startup group at
`C:\Users\USER-NAME\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup`.

Useful AutoHotkey documentation:

- [List of Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm)

Comment: Another free keyboard shortcut tool is Clavier+, https://gryder.org/software/clavier-plus/ . BTW, the Windows key is called the *System key* in Linux and other OS's.

Comment: Thanks, both solutions were great, and I was looking more towards a GUI solution, so Glyder is a great option. However, specifically, the Start+T combination is not supported there - it doesn't override Windows' default one (unless there's some option to do that that I didn't see).

Answer (score 1):

Any shortcut on the Desktop or Start menu can have a hotkey set, but not using the Winkey. To prevent conflicts within programs as this will override program shortcuts, you may use Ctrl + Alt + <letter> or the function keys.

Right click a shortcut to a program on the Desktop and choose *Properties*. Put the text caret into the textbox with a label of *Shortcut Key* and press Ctrl + Alt + T.

If a program is started this way and it is still running then pressing the shortcut key will switch to the running window.